# ASP.NET 5 - DataSet, DataTable and friends

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm creating a new webservice in ASP.NET 5 using the new .NET Core library, so far I've only hit an issue with using DataSet and DataTable.

According to [this](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/1039) site they are not included at this moment in time, which is fine, but I don't know what alternatives I have at this time, so I'm just looking for some guidance.

I have the following code:
        public string Get(string p_sUserId, string p_sUserPassword, int p_iCustId)
        {
            Select qrySelect = new Select();

```
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Startup.ConnectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qrySelect.getData(), conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", sTestId);

                using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
                    {
                        // foo
                        // bar
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return "value";
    }
```

How should I handle the data that is being return from the query? I need to build and return a string using the above data fetched from the query. Any help and guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: I believe you could use Entity Framework 7

Comment: @eddie_31003 - As part of the specification for this particular job, I unfortunately can't make use of Entity Framework. Thank you for your suggestion though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe [SqlDataReader](https://dotnet.github.io/api/System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.html#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlCommand_ExecuteReader) should work.

```
       string sql = "SELECT * FROM Table";
       using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Startup.ConnectionString)) {
            con.Open();
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, con)) {

                using (IDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader()) {
                    while (dr.Read()) {
                        //process data
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for this, hopefully they bring back DataSet and DataTable in future versions.

Answer (score 0):

DataTable and SqlDBAdapter are now supported using .NET Standard 2.0.  Upgrade to VS2017 Preview, add System.Data.Common and System.Data.SqlClient nugets, and the code below should work.  More detail at the blog post here ->  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devfish/2017/05/15/exploring-datatable-and-sqldbadapter-in-asp-net-core-2-0/ .  GitHub repo here -> https://github.com/jhealy/aspdotnetcore/tree/master/SqlClientPlay20 .

```
public static DataTable ExecuteDataTableSqlDA(SqlConnection conn, CommandType cmdType, string cmdText, SqlParameter[] cmdParms)
{
    System.Data.DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdText, conn);
    da.Fill(dt);
    return dt;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for adding this so long after the question was closed.

Comment: Read the question when looking for the answer.  Figured others would do the same.